# Print to another page without filling the whole previous page

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I have a code in vb.net that prints a couple datagridview, and each page is supposed to print 2 dgv. I know there is a regular code that when it fills the whole page, it goes to the next page, but usually my dgv does not fill the whole page, and I wish it skip the whole blank space that the first 2 dgv did not fill and starts printing the third dgv in the next page.

```
printdgvLeft(gridFormas, e, txtCliente.Text, txtRepresentante.Text)
printdgvRight(gridDoces, e, txtCliente.Text, txtRepresentante.Text)

e.HasMorePages = True

printdgvLeft(gridPVC, e, txtCliente.Text, txtRepresentante.Text)
e.HasMorePages = False
```

I tried something like this, but it seems is does not work.
Any help will nice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the printdgvRight & printdgvLeft methods?  Any chance you could expand your question a little so we've got a complete method?  Don't really have any idea what e is

Comment: Whether a pagr is "filled" or not ir irrelevant. The `PrintPage` event handler prints one page. That's it, that's all. If you want to print one word on that page then that's what your code should do. What could possibly be the point of setting `HasMorePages` twice in the same `PrintPage` event handler? All that matters is its value when the method completes. If it is `True` then the event is raosed again to print another page. If it's `False` then you're done. Print what you want to print one the current page and set `HasMorePages` to `True` if there's more to print. Simple.

Comment: @Hursey Sorry, Those two methods means that the printdgvright will print the dgv on the right part of the paper, while the printdgvleft will print on the left page of the paper. So, as I said I will have more than 2 dgvs, and I can only have 2 dgvs per paper.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for your time, couple more questions when I put only one `hasmorepages` it will increase the pages infinitely. And plus, when I click cancel, the third dgv does not print on the next page, still print in the first page and over the first dgv.

Comment: `when I put only one hasmorepages it will increase the pages infinitely`. Then your logic is wrong, so you need to spend more time working out the logic first, then writing code to specifically implement that logic.

Comment: @jmcilhinney For example if I put `HasMorePages = true ` why it increases infinitely the page of number until i click cancel?

Comment: If you only ever set `HasMorePages` to `True` then of course it keeps printing pages infinitely, because you're always telling it that there are more pages to print. Use your head! You need to implement logic to determine whether there is more data to print and set `HasMorePages` to `True` or `False` based on that. You set it to one or the other, not both. If you do both then only the last one matters because that's what it is when the method completes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ok sir. I think you are a little stressed with me, my bad. Thanks for your time.